# During trying to Recode my data I keep running into Error: Argument 2 must be named, not unnamed

Tags: r, error-handling, recode

I am pretty new to R and keep running into error messages. Usually some patience and googling can help me out but right now I am at a loss.

I have yesterday created a script in which I recode some factor data to have only 3 regions instead of 18 countries (it is part of a course assignment). It worked great yesterday, but today I wanted to coninue and get the following error:

Error: Argument 2 must be named, not unnamed

The code I have been running is:

```r
data$regions <- recode(data$country, "c('China','Japan')='Asia'; c('United States')='North America';else='Europe'", as.factor = T)
```

and I have 18 countries, and the data set includes over 6000 observations.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Are you using ```recode``` from the ```dplyr``` library?

Comment: I expect you've loaded `dplyr` after loading the `car` package so `recode()`  has been masked from `car`.  Use `car::recode()` or be careful about the order in which you load packages that share function names.

Answer (score 1):

As @H1 pointet out, you want to use

```r
car::recode(data$region, "c('China','Japan')='Asia'; c('United States')='North America';else='Europe'", as.factor = T)
```

So why the error?

```
recode()
```

As a function exists in several packages with different arguments.

```
dplyr::recode()

car::recode()
...
```

So you should always be more explicit which libraries you have loaded and which function you actually want to use.

Comment: actually I understand what I did wrong and your comment helped. i feel really stupid now, but I forgot to load the package! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are various method to do that.

To begin with, you could simply use dplyr:: case_when

```
data$regions <- with(data, dplyr::case_when(country %in% c('China','Japan') ~ 'Asia',
                                            country == 'United States' ~ 'North America',
                                            TRUE ~ 'Europe')
```